# How to purge uBlock filter caches in Firefox after 1.55

Tags: firefox, ublock-origin

There are legitimate use-cases to purge filter caches, but Git commit [#bd7ce41](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/commit/bd7ce41224) for uBlock made it harder. How to purge uBlock filter caches in Firefox after 1.55?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'm dealing with it for now in Firefox.

1. Open uBO setting and find its ID (it changes on different profiles)

   [image: ublock id]
2. Close the browser and go to your Firefox profile

   ```
   ./storage/default
   ```

   [image: linux path]
3. Delete the folder `moz-extension+++{ID}`, make a backup if you're not sure. Don't touch the folder with `^userContextId`, this folder contains your uBO config.

Now the filters should be re-fetched on browser start, as with the past purge-update workflow.

Comment: Nice self-solved question!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thanks for the formatting cleanup!